# Nock do not intercept redux action creator request

Tags: reactjs, redux, nock

I'm trying to test my first action creator using `nock`. I'm following the redux [documentation](http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/WritingTests.html#async-action-creators). Here is my code

```
import configureMockStore from 'redux-mock-store'
import thunk from 'redux-thunk'
import nock from 'nock'

const middlewares = [ thunk ]
const mockStore = configureMockStore(middlewares)

describe('(Action creator)', () => {
  beforeEach((done) => {
    nock.disableNetConnect();
    done()
  })

  afterEach((done) => {
    nock.cleanAll()
    nock.enableNetConnect();
    done()
  })

  describe('#loginUser', () => {
    it('should login user', () => {
      const initialState = {
        isFetching: false,
        isAuthenticated: false,
      };

      const expectedActions = [
        { type: LOGIN_REQUEST,
          isFetching: true,
          isAuthenticated: false,
          credentials: {
            email: 'test@test.com',
            password: 'test',
          }},
        { type: LOGIN_SUCCESS,
          isFetching: false,
          isAuthenticated: true,
          id_token: 'idtoken',
        }
      ]
      const store = mockStore(initialState)

      nock('http://localhost:4000')
        .post('/auth/login', '*')
        .reply(200, { body: { token: 'idtoken' } })

      return store
        .dispatch(loginUser({ email: 'test@test.com', password: 'test' }))
        .then(() => {
          expect(store.getActions()).to.deep.equal(expectedActions)
        })
    })
  })
```

The test fails at the assertion because nock does a real request to the server and receive a real token, not a fake one. Here are the log I can see on the server side

```
::ffff:127.0.0.1 - - [17/Oct/2016:15:05:28 +0000] "OPTIONS /auth/login HTTP/1.1" 204 -
::ffff:127.0.0.1 - - [17/Oct/2016:15:05:28 +0000] "POST /auth/login HTTP/1.1" 200 427
```

Did I miss something ? Why is `nock` doing a real request even with the use of `nock.disableNetConnect();`